# Is there anything like Meshmixer's "Make solid" in Blender?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, 3d-printing

I have a mesh with a lot of self intersections I got from running the shell modifier and I will later do some Booleans on it and then 3d print it. The trouble is the intersections throw off the Boolean modifier and make it give inconsistent results so these intersections must be removed before this step. Is there a way to remove these intersection automatically? Right now my workflow involves exporting the model to Meshmixer, running "make solid" and then importing the stl back into Blender. Is there a way to keep the workflow in Blender without adding hours of manual cleanup to remove hundreds of self intersections? If possible I'd like to keep the workflow entirely in Blender for scripting and license purposes in the end use case.

Comment: We don't really know what "*make solid*" from Meshmixer does so we can't tell for sure, but I am guessing there is no equivalent in Blender. That fact that you rely heavily on Boolean operations for modelling is generally a red flag. Either use proper modelling techniques suited for mesh geometry, or prefer some ACIS Solids or NURBS based 3D software which is generally more tolerant of Boolean heavy workflows.

Comment: The problem is I'm working with organic scan data which is inherently a mesh and not easily made parametric. Boolean operations shouldn't be a problem for static models that will later be 3d printed as slicers don't care about topology so long as the result is manifold.

Answer (score 1):

Remesh Modifier is Blenders equivalent of Make Solid in Meshmixer. But the results are unpredictable most of the time so I suggest you stick to Meshmixer for that operation.

Comment: Unfortunately remesh appears not to make a manifold mesh if the octree level is high enough to capture all the detail. It mostly just changes the surface topology.